# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Cannot navigate to invalid URL when I am passing valid URLS

Tags: javascript, html, electron, puppeteer

I am trying to use a puppeteer to scrape the product title of an amazon item in an electron app.
The exact test url I am using is
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B088CK6GP1?pf_rd_r=X4CXHQ3R45BFH3T0VF4X&pf_rd_p=05326fd5-c43e-4948-99b1-a65b129fdd73&pd_rd_r=8146d8bb-8a19-46d1-a3c8-936ace2ee64e&pd_rd_w=63lRt&pd_rd_wg=OOZ2e&ref_=pd_gw_unk

which works when I run it in a separate test file but not in the electron app and I can't find a way to fix the error

Here is the scraper file

```html
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

getname = async function(url){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector('#productTitle')
    const name = await page.evaluate(() => {
       return document.getElementById("productTitle").innerText;
    })
    await browser.close();
    return name;
}



module.exports = { getname };
```

the test file

```html
const scraper = require('./scrape.js');

const url = "https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B088CK6GP1?pf_rd_r=F20ADBW6SQS0H1MCSSMC&pf_rd_p=05326fd5-c43e-4948-99b1-a65b129fdd73&pd_rd_r=d92fb039-6465-47e1-bda2-6d75b9f5104e&pd_rd_w=UeD0T&pd_rd_wg=SoFi6&ref_=pd_gw_unk";
const name = scraper.getname(url);
name.then(function(resualt){
    console.log(typeof resualt);
    console.log(resualt);
})
```

the electron code. The part that uses the scraper is under //catch item:add

```html
const electron = require('electron');
const scraper = require('./scrape.js');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const { protocol } = require('electron');
const { stringify } = require('querystring');

const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain} = electron;

let mainWindow;
let addWindow;

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

// Listen for the app to be ready


app.on('ready', function(){
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }
    });
    //load html
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainwindow.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));
    //Quit app when closed
    mainWindow.on('closed', function(){
        app.quit();
    })
    //build main menu
    const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
    //insert menu
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu)

});

//Handel add window

function createAddWindow(){
    addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        title: 'Add Item',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }
    });

    //load html
    addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'addwindow.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    //Garbage collection
    addWindow.on('close', function(){
        addWindow = null;
    });
}

function createLogWindow(){
    addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        title: 'Add Item',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }
    });

    //load html
    addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'login.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    //Garbage collection
    addWindow.on('close', function(){
        addWindow = null;
    });
}


//catch item:add

ipcMain.on('item:add', function(e, item){
    const link = JSON.stringify(item);
    console.log(link);
    const name = scraper.getname(link);
    name.then(function(resualt){
        console.log(resualt);
        mainWindow.webContents.send('item:add', resualt);
    })
    addWindow.close();
});

ipcMain.on('details', function(e, details){
    console.log(details["email"]);
    console.log(details["password"]);
    addWindow.close();
});



//create menu template

const mainMenuTemplate = [
    {
        label: 'Flie',
        submenu:[
            {
                label: 'Add Item',
                click(){
                    createAddWindow();
                }
            },
            {
                label: 'Clear Item',
                click(){
                    mainWindow.webContents.send('item:clear');
                }
            },
            {
                label: 'Run Check',
                accelerator: process.platform == 'darwin' ? 'Comamand+R' :
                'Ctrl+R',
                click(){
                    createLogWindow();
                }
            },
            {
                label: 'Quit',
                accelerator: process.platform == 'darwin' ? 'Comamand+Q' :
                'Ctrl+Q',
                click(){
                    app.quit();
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];

//If mac add empty object to menu
if(process.platform == 'darwin'){
    mainMenuTemplate.unshift({});
}

// add dev tool if not in production

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    mainMenuTemplate.push({
        label: "Developer Tools",
        submenu:[
            {
                label: 'Toggle Dev Tools',
                accelerator: process.platform == 'darwin' ? 'Comamand+I' :
                'Ctrl+I',
                click(item, focusedWindow){
                    focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();
                }
            },
            {
                role: 'reload'
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

I am completely new to JS,electorn, and puppeteer and I am sorry for any glareing errors.

Comment: What is logged by `console.log(link);`?

Comment: "https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B088CK6GP1?pf_rd_r=BM5R67MPPVHADH55DSN1&pf_rd_p=05326fd5-c43e-4948-99b1-a65b129fdd73&pd_rd_r=67861fb7-b9d9-49b5-87a1-a6fe8814d5b6&pd_rd_w=Jnvug&pd_rd_wg=1WF2X&ref_=pd_gw_unk"

Answer (score 1):

```js
const link = JSON.stringify(item);
```

It seems you already have the URL string in `item`. `JSON.stringify(item)` returns the same string wrapped in quotes. These quotes make URL string invalid. Try this instead:

```js
const link = item;
```

Or, if item is an object with some `toJSON()` and `toString()` methods that return URL, try this:

```js
const link = String(item);
```

Or even this:

```js
const link = JSON.stringify(item).slice(1, -1);
```